# If existence cannot be proven

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

If existence cannot be proven, apart from as a state of mind, is there any real way in which we can suggest this is true?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Philosophy SE. Please visit our [Help Center](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help) to see what questions we answer and how to ask. One-line posts are discouraged because it is hard to tell from them what people are looking for. Nothing can be "proven", including "states of mind", if "proven" means absolute certainty. And if it is less than that, most people find themselves and their  surroundings "real" enough. Could you provide some context for your question?

Comment: Suggest what is true? That existence is a product of Mind? This can be proved in logic, as is demonstrated by Nagarjuna and others, and some would say by Kant and Bradley. If existence could be proven to be more than conceptual then the plot-line of the Matrix film franchise wouldn't work. The perennial view would be that existence is Mind-dependent while the Real would transcend the distinction between existence and non-existence. So yes, we can definitely suggest it is true that existence is a state of mind and if you do you'll be in excellent company.

Comment: Does everything require a proof?

Comment: You are "metaphysical" in the sense that you place mind as premise earlier to what it is defined as (the experience of a phenomenon). Actually existence is immediate and needs not be proven, it isn't a "state of" anything.

Comment: There is no way to prove the true, independent or independent existence of anything. If there were then the Perennial philosophy would immediately look ridiculous. Better to ask why we cannot prove it since out inability to do so should tell us something.

Comment: @GeoffreyThomas - You are free to check out the arguments, proofs and evidence. They won't fit into a comment box.

Comment: @PeterJ. It's a while since I made the comment. I have no concern to defend it.

Comment: @PeterJ . Sorry for my abrupt comment. The explanation. not the excuse, is that I was in the middle of thinking about something else - an answer on Aristotle, justice & friendship. We won't be allowed to talk at length here : you can contact me on peruviansun@gmail.com. I always value your ideas and arguments.

Comment: @GeoffreyThomas - No problem. These 'comment' discussions are fraught with danger, as I'm discovering.

Answer (score 2):

> If existence cannot be proven, apart from as a state of mind, is there any real way in which we can suggest this is true?

If I may rephrase the question: Existence cannot be proven, apart from as a state of mind. Therefore, the question becomes, "Does reality exist for **individuals**, without minds to perceive it?"

Answer: *Collectively*, we know that existence is real. But for each **individual**, it is only real while they live and have a mind with which to experience it. So existence is simultaneously both, absolute and transitory. *Unless* the mind somehow survives the death of the body, in which case we cannot know the truth of the matter until it is our turn to die.

So there are two possible realities **accessible to individual experience**:

1. The individual mind survives the death of the body, and learns that existence is absolute. Then proceeds to deal with reality as it is perceived within that particular circumstance.
2. The individual mind doesn't survive the death of the body, and from that point on learns no more and remembers nothing. In the latter case, existence would no longer be of any concern to the individual, because the question becomes moot. Without a mind to perceive and form thoughts, existence becomes transitory.

Answer (score 1):

In philosophical sense, what do you mean by the term--'to prove'?

Since your question is about 'existence', 'real' and 'proving', I think the analysis must go too deep. Here the proving is about existence we cannot treat this as an ordinary question.In any way you should know what the real problem is.

I don't know whether you would agree this: The existence can never be a nonexistence. It needs nobody's proof.

> See: Bhagavad Gita 2.16
>
> *nasato vidyate bhavo nabhavo vidyate satah*
> *ubhayor api drsto 'ntas tv anayos tattva-darsibhih*
>
> **Meaning**: Those who are seers of the truth have concluded that of the
> nonexistent there is no endurance, and of the existent there is no
> cessation. This seers have concluded by studying the nature of both.

But when we usually prove existence practically, what we are actually doing is whether the thing that exists can effect our five sense organs. If no effect, "no existence", we say.

If so, **When you consider existence as something that can give impulses for our sense organs, you are considering all the other things for perception as another entity (existence). Then you will have to conclude that 'existence is divided'.** This is a folly.

You'd better think on this than my complicated explanation.

So, **IF THE AFORESAID LOGIC IS TRUE**, even in real sense (I mean, even if you do believe this material world as real) **you can't prove EXISTENCE.**

All created beings are unmanifest before birth, manifest in life, and again unmanifest on death. These three states are essential to all lifeless things also.  Since this material world undergoes changes, **one gets the proof of existence (beingness) ONLY 'as' self realization.**  The image that follows might help you verify this.

Here I have explained the rarest possibility of 'when/how existence can be proven'.

The following example might be useful in this context:

When we watch a movie we know it is the screen that actually exists.  But we know this truth only after the movie ended. Here we are aware of the truth because we knew it (the screen) before or/and after the show. Similarly, we know the truth of existence only after our illusion or delusion ended. In other words, in the case of movie, we have an experience of either/both of these situations.  So we know the truth.  But in real life this is seldom possible. That is the problem.

As for conclusion, knowingly or unknowingly, what you meant by the term existence is none other than **BEINGNESS**. And that real way **MUST BE THE PROOF WITHOUT SENSES.** [Here the real way and the proof become one (Please refer the question)]. 'Proving' is an action. But there is no action to existence.

If I am allowed to summarize the idea of existence, I would say "All the problem is due to the misconception or ignorance about the **truth** of existence."

What is **subtler** than mind...? The following image might help you to know more about  it (Don't be confused.  For convenience the image is given as concentric circles).

[image]

Try to know more about the 5 sheaths from different websites. Just for an example: http://www.sivanandaonline.org/public_html/?cmd=displaysection&section_id=775

You will understand that mind is not necessary for realizing (not for proving) that existence. Try to understand why the author in the link call 'it' existence and consciousness for salutation/praying as a specially selected word.

Answer (score 1):

The first clause of your question is misleading and unwanted. Why?

We are living in a world created by our senses. And for normal perception mind must function properly.

We are able to prove something only when we are in waking state.  And in no time the mind begins to do its function without any break.  This means mind interferes while proving anything.

But some people realize existence in the 'fourth state' of consciousness called '[Thuriya](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8726124)'...without any disturbance of mind. See this also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turiya

Only such people know what the only reality/existence is.

But others can argue against it more vigorously, since they are very great in  number.  If elected they will certainly win.

See the 2 possibilities:

Either... (**Category 1**) Those who knew existence...are in delusion. [So we can't believe their words.]

or... (**Category 2**) Those who didn't yet know existence...are in delusion. [So we can't believe their words.]

You may argue for a third possibility also: "Both are wrong."

Certainly one of these two categories must be in delusion.  But how can we know **whose way is real?** (or way of **Category 1** is real? or **Category 2** is in delusion?)

We (others) know that the words of **Category 1** is true, not at the time they realize existence...but after realization...sometimes after their death...sometimes when we realize ourselves...sometimes when science reaches closer and closer to that findings. [Read the Hyperlink given above.]

Answer (score 0):

This is a little outside my realm of expertise, but my view about this is that if you're talking about 'suggest' rather than prove, then persistence and consistency of perceived reality already do that.

I go to work; I drive, so I park my car and walk to the office. At the end of the day, I walk back to my car, pay for my parking, drive home to my house where my wife and boys are.

I can remember now what my wife and what my children look like. I can remember what my house looks like, and where it is. I remember what my car looks like and I remember where I've parked it and how much it's going to cost me for the parking today.

Every time I move my field of sensory inputs (basically, my head but my body generally) to a place that doesn't contain my house, car, family, etc. all I have is my sensory memory of them. But, I also remember walking back to my car literally thousands of times; I remember my house being where it is and I have a high level of confidence that when I go back to my car at the end of a working day it'll be there; that my family will be in my home and it'll be where I last saw it when I get there.

This tells me one of 3 things;

1) My senses are reporting an objective reality correctly
2) The subjective reality I hold in mind is at least consistent
3) If my senses are lying to me, then they have to be altering my memories as well.

If we take a reductionist approach, or apply Occam's Razor to this problem, we can see that any of these could be possible. But, 3 is more complicated to maintain. On the surface, 2 looks like the simplest but it doesn't account for changes outside my control; my car could be stolen for instance, in which case when it turns up as a burnt out shell 2 days later and they catch who did it, that person can account for the existence of the vehicle and the change in state and location over the intervening period. That's pretty hard to maintain when you multiply that by 7 bn actors (humans alone, doesn't count the cat eating that rat that's been terrorising your pantry).

What this leaves us with is that the simplest explanation is that our senses are reporting an objective reality correctly. Is this a proof? Of course not. But, it is a suggestion that what we see is objectively 'correct'.

As a side point, this is one of the approaches that can be used on people with Schizophrenia, drug problems or other mental health issues that cause hallucinations; are the hallucinations consistent with the rest of your experience? No? then perhaps they're not real...

Philosophically of course, they're VERY real because they are a part of a person's actual experiences. But, I suspect I'm drifting out of the scope of the question so I'll leave it there.

Answer (score 0):

It kind of sounds like you're asking "If x cannot be proven, is there any way to prove x?"  to which the answer is necessarily no.  Do you mean to ask can the existence of non-mental entities be proven?

Lets assume there are only states of mind.  Any state of mind would need to be caused by something else, and there are only states of mind, so all states of mind are caused by other states of mind.  For example, my state of mind when seeing one billiard ball striking another causes the following state of mind where the struck ball gains momentum.  It seems reasonable to assume that there are consistent rules of cause and effect between states of mind.  Concepts such as "mass" can be used to explain why a certain outcome occurred.  However, the mass of the billiard balls doesn't seem to be a part of my mental state and yet it still seems to affect the resulting state of mind.  In other words, there seems to be something outside of my mental experience that affects what mental state results, in this case the billiard's intrinsic property of having a certain mass.  If there is some thing outside of my state of mind that has intrinsic properties that is influencing the resulting mental state, isn't that what we mean by something that is physical?

Answer (score 0):

Existence can't be proven objectively, but the simple process of questioning existence, proves existence. If you did not exist, you could not ask the question, "Do I exist?", therefore you know you exist. But proving you exist to someone else is impossible. We can postulate which is the most plausible view, but ultimately, every view relies on accepting an ultimate truth which is unprovable.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It is true, but not true considering what you think about it, but what you experience here and now beyond duality, because everything generated by the mind are just metaphysical tools, the rest is true, your senses are true human senses, that shows the truth of what beeing a human is, and you live a world of your senses, so it is true, but not the whole true.

The whole truth is liberty, search the truth beyong the truth inside yourself and the answers that are more profound may come. To go deeper inside the mind in search of yourself, you have to keep on discarding thoughts using the "I dont know" answer to yourself, lapidating your Philosopher's stone. Greetings from the abysm. I really dont speak english well, so keep the truth and throw what I said away. Peace.

Comment: Your English is pretty good. This answer would be more clear, and helpful to others, if you divided your thoughts into several sentences.